# Image upload and display without page refresh jquery mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-uploading

I tried few solution to avoid page refresh on image upload (client side) and display using jquery but it doesn't work. Here is my code for image upload and display:

```
 $("input[type='image']").click(function() {
            $("input[id='my_file']").click();
        });
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $('#imgUser').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#my_file").change(function() {
            readURL(this);
        });
```

This work quit nice but problem is that, it does refresh form while uploading an image, as a result my model(other input field) being clear. Is it possible to restrict form refresh on image upload and display with my current code? any suggestion and help is appreciable.Thanks in advance.

I attached my Html(Cshtml) code here of image upload:

```
<input type="image" id="imgUser" class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="~/CommonResources/images/no-Image.jpg" alt="User profile picture">
<input type="file" id="my_file" name="files" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: forget about the FileReader and use URL.createObjectURL to preview and possible FormData for uploading files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check if this is what you want.**

HTML:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" style="display:none" />
        <img id="blah" style="border-radius:50%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="your image" height="100px" width="100px" />
    </form>
```

Javascript (Jquery):

```
//select file - image
$('#blah').click(function() {
  $('#imgInp').click();
})

//preview the image
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

**Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/72211/**

*Note: I didn't see any page refreshes. Your code just seems fine to me*

Comment: I just used <img> instead of <input type="image"...> it works fine. Thanks